# C++ Spawning threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

Hello i need a hand on spawning a thread properly, i cant seem to get the syntax correct. 
here is my code ...

```
// Spawn a thread--------------------------------------------------#    
    pthread_t thread1;  // thread object
    int rc1;

    if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, spellCheck, NULL)) )
    {
        cout << "Thread creation failed: " << rc1 << endl;
    }

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
```

function definition

```
void spellCheck(vector<string> * fileRead, list<string> * incorrectWord, vector<string> * correctWord)
{
```

header file

```
void spellCheck(vector<string> *fileRead, list<string> *incorrectWord, vector<string> *correctWord);
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

my error:

```
server.cpp:142: error: invalid conversion from 'void ()(std::vector<std:................. initializing argument 3 of 'int pthread_create(pthread_t, const pthread_attr_t*, void* ()(void), void*)'
```

Comment: server.cpp:142: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(std::vector<std:................. initializing argument 3 of 'int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)' @SLaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong here but I thought that the thread function you implement and pass to pthread_create() could only have a single (void*) input argument

Comment: ohk i understand what your getting at